# flutter Transform.translate animation from and to center of widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

in this below animation implemented to make center for translate animation to use both of `elasticIn` and `elasticOut`

unfortunately my implemented is not center of widget and i can't set it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()=>runApp(MaterialApp(home: App(),));

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>_App();
}

class _App extends State<App> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animationRadiusIn;
  Animation<double> animationRadiusOut;

  final double initialRadius = 55.0;
  double radius = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 5));

    animationRadiusIn =
        Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.5).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Interval(0.75, 1.0, curve: Curves.elasticIn)));
    animationRadiusOut =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0.5, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Interval(0.0, 0.25, curve: Curves.elasticOut)));

    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        if (controller.value >= 0.75 && controller.value <= 1.0) {
          radius = animationRadiusIn.value * initialRadius;
        } else if (controller.value >= 0.0 && controller.value <= 0.25) {
          radius = animationRadiusOut.value * initialRadius;
        }
      });
    });

    controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(radius,radius),
              child:FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

make animation from center of widget for both of `elasticIn` and `elasticOut` animations

that means starting and ending `Curves.elasticIn` and `Curves.elasticOut` animations from and to center

Comment: and why dont you use `AlignTransition` / `SlideTransition`?

Comment: see [this](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/align_transition.mp4) and [this](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/slide_transition.mp4)

Comment: @pskink that means starting and ending `Curves.elasticIn` and `Curves.elasticOut` animations from and to center

Answer (score 1):

I've tried observing the behavior of your code. Here is the output from your implementation:

[image]

What I've observed is on how you set where the animation will begin. Based from the documentation of [elasticIn](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves/elasticIn-constant.html) and [elasticOut](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves/elasticOut-constant.html):

Tried to switch the value of `begin` and `end` from both `animationRadiusIn` and `animationRadiusOut`

```
animationRadiusIn = Tween<double>(begin: 0.5, end: 1.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: Interval(0.75, 1.0, curve: Curves.elasticIn)));
animationRadiusOut = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.5).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: Interval(0.0, 0.25, curve: Curves.elasticOut)));
```

And here is the output:

[image]

It is more centered than the previous, and changing the value of `begin: 0.0` in `animationRadiusIn` and the `end: 0.0` in `animationRadiusOut` made the animation start and end from the center. I think that's where you need to set it.

```
animationRadiusIn = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
            CurvedAnimation(
                parent: controller,
                curve: Interval(0.75, 1.0, curve: Curves.elasticIn)));
animationRadiusOut = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(
            CurvedAnimation(
                parent: controller,
                curve: Interval(0.0, 0.25, curve: Curves.elasticOut)));
```

[image]